# Initial and final structures

Tags: reference-request, category-theory

Let $\def\A{\mathcal{A}}\def\B{\mathcal{B}}\def\id{\operatorname{id}}U: \A \to \B$ be a faithful functor. Without loss of generality, objects of $\A$ are pairs $(X, τ)$ where $X$ is an object of $\B$ and $τ ∈ \A(X)$ is a “structure on $X$”. We may also view $\A((X, τ), (Y, σ)) ⊆ \B(X, Y)$. Let us define a pre-order on every $\A(X)$: $τ_1 ≤ τ_2$ iff $\id_X ∈ \A(τ_1, τ_2)$. A typical example is $U: \mathbf{Top} \to \mathbf{Set}$.

Let $f_i: X \to (Y_i, σ_i)$ be family of maps. The *initial structure* for the family is the $≤$-largest element $τ ∈ \A(X)$ such that $f_i ∈ \A(τ, σ_i)$ for every $i$. Let us consider also the following condition $(*)$: for every $g: (X', τ') \to X$ we have $f_i ∘ g ∈ \A(τ', σ_i)$ for every $i$ iff $g ∈ \A(τ', τ)$. Note that being an initial structure is $(*)$ only for $g = \id_X$, so $(*)$ is stronger. Dually we can define final structures.

1. Is $(*)$ strictly stronger? It seems that the extra ingredient is the following “interpolation property”: for every $f: (X, τ) \to Y$ and $g: Y \to (Z, σ)$ such that $g ∘ f ∈ \A(τ, σ)$ there is $ρ ∈ \A(Y)$ such that $f ∈ \A(τ, ρ)$ and $g ∈ \A(ρ, σ)$.
2. It is sometimes the case that the limit in $\A$ is the limit in $\B$ endowed with the initial structure, but it seems that the stronger property $(*)$ is needed for this. Am I right?
3. Is there a standard reference regarding this issue?

Comment: I don't follow your "without loss of generality" in the first paragraph. What is $\mathcal{A}(X)$? Should one of the $\mathcal{A}$s be a $\mathcal{B}$?

Comment: @AlexKruckman Yes, sorry, the first one should have been $\mathcal{B}$. Fixed in the quiestion now. $\mathcal{A}(X)$ is essentialy $U^{-1}(X)$ – different structures on the same underlying object.

Comment: I see, thanks for clarifying. It seems like a very special property of the categories involved that initial structures exist at all. e.g. if $U$ reflects isomorphism, as is the case for forgetful functors from categories of algebraic structures, then the $\leq$ pre-orders will all be discrete.

Comment: @AlexKruckman: Yes, these are called topological functors or topological concrete categories. Besides Top, the same sitution occur in categories of relational structures.

Comment: The result that (*) is stronger is a remark (proof left as an exercise) in Bourbaki Vol 1, ch IV sec 2.3 on Initial Structures. It's given in a structuralist context rather than a categorical one, so some translation is needed.